# Get data from another data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

My data frame df1:

```
    ID    Date
0   90  02/01/2021
1   101 01/01/2021
2   30  12/01/2021
```

My data frame df2:

```
    ID  City  01/01/2021    02/01/2021  12/01/2021
0   90    A     20            14          22
1   101   B     15            10          5
2   30    C     12            9           13
```

I need to create a column in df1 'New'. It should contain data from df2 with respect to 'ID' and 'Date' of df1. I am finding difficult in merging data. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df22 = df2.drop('City', 1).melt(['ID'], var_name='Date', value_name='Val')
df = df1.merge(df22, how='left')
print (df)
    ID        Date  Val
0   90  02/01/2021   14
1  101  01/01/2021   15
2   30  12/01/2021   13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `melt` and `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2.melt(id_vars=['ID', 'City'], var_name='Date'), on=['ID', 'Date'])
```

output:

```
    ID        Date City  value
0   90  02/01/2021    A     14
1  101  01/01/2021    B     15
2   30  12/01/2021    C     13
```

Alternative:

```
df1.merge(df2.melt(id_vars='ID',
                   value_vars=df2.filter(regex='/'),
                   var_name='Date'),
          on=['ID', 'Date'])
```

output:

```
    ID        Date  value
0   90  02/01/2021     14
1  101  01/01/2021     15
2   30  12/01/2021     13
```